# emberjs model not called when rendering template in outlet

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to render a project show template, and inside it im trying to render cards new template with corresponding route/model/controller.

[According to documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render) I can call render method in projects show route to render templates in outlets, but for some reason model function is not called when rendering. These are my routes

```
App.ProjectsShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    this.store.unloadAll('project');
    this.store.unloadAll('card');
    return this.store.find('project', params.project_id);
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this._super();
    return this.render('cards/index', {
      into: 'projects/show',
      outlet: 'CardsIndex'
    });
  }
});

App.CardsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    debugger;
    return this.store.find('card');
  }
});

// ---
// generated by coffee-script 1.9.0
```

CardsIndex controller and template are loaded correctly.

Comment: can you show me JS code rather than coffee script.

Comment: why are you unloading the models. Have to tried to remove the unload statement. Also can you post your template. What is the name of your outlet exactly.

Comment: Outlet names are right and templates get rendered correctly when I specify model in render call as parameter. I will post them once I get to a computer. Issue is that route for CardsIndex is not touched as if it doesn't exist. And I also don't see that route being generated in console. I think documentation might be wrong and route is never accessed when you use render unless it means the model of current route which is ProjectsShow.